# Flutter keeps saying error: Unable to read manifest info from app.apk directory

Tags: android, flutter, android-studio

I keep getting this error no matter what I do. I have upgraded flutter, deleted the app.apk from its directory in build folder, did flutter clean. Nothing is helping

```
Unable to read manifest info from D:\Documents\ema1\build\app\outputs\flutter-apk\app.apk.
No application found for TargetPlatform.android_x64.
Is your project missing an android\app\src\main\AndroidManifest.xml?
Consider running "flutter create ." to create one.
```

Answer (score 1):

Step 1: Go to AndroidManifest.xml

Add package="com.example" , repalce with your own package name.

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example">
```

Step 2:

```
flutter clean
```

Step 3:

```
flutter pub get
```

Hope it will solve your issue.

Comment: I did that but now its showing only - Unable to read manifest info from D:\Documents\ema1\build\app\outputs\flutter-apk\app.apk. Exception: Problem building Android application: see above error(s).

Comment: delete your build folder manually once and try again

Comment: I did, it still did not work